# Does every normal subgroup appear as a kernel of an irreducible representation? 

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Given a finite group and a normal subgroup, does there always exist an irreducible complex representation, whose kernel is this normal subgroup?

Sorry, just it was just mentioned that this is a duplicate. See [Which finite groups have faithful complex irreducible representations?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57129/which-finite-groups-have-faithful-complex-irreducible-representations).

Comment: I think the answer is clearly no. Irreducible complex representations of abelian groups are 1-dimensional, while every subgroup is normal. So no proper normal subgroup can be the kernel of an irreducible representation.


Comment: Well, for finite abelian groups the kernels of irreducible complex representations would be the subgroups such that the quotient is cyclic. 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

take the canonical quotient $q:G\rightarrow G/H$ and $\lambda :G/H\rightarrow U(n)$ to be the left-regular representation of $G/H$, where $n=|G/H|$, then the composition is the map that you are looking for, unless I am missing something...

**Edit:** if you consider irreducible representations, then the answer is no for the group $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Sorry forgot the adjective "irreducible" before.

Comment: for the irreducible case, the answer is no, see above

Comment: the sum of $3$ terms of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is just for having proper normal subgroup. But if you don't want to assume this, the answer of BS is completely describes the situation.

Answer (score 5):

In the new formulation (irreducible rep), the question is wether any finite group has a faithful irreducible complex representation. This is false for noncyclic abelian groups. A more complete answer is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57129/which-finite-groups-have-faithful-complex-irreducible-representations)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, consider the quotient by this normal subgroup, embeds it into symmetric group of $n$ letters with $n$ large enough, identify symmetric group with a subgroup of $GL(n)$, you get the representation.

Comment: Good answer, forgot the adjective "irreducible". Is it still true?