# A dual version of a theorem of Øystein Ore in group theory

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, lattice-theory, algebraic-combinatorics

This post is a dual version for the [Generalization of a theorem of Øystein Ore](https://mathoverflow.net/q/179555/34538) in which [it's proved](https://mathoverflow.net/a/195331/34538):
*Theorem*:  Let $[H, G]$ be a  distributive interval of finite groups. Then $\exists g \in G$ such that $\langle H,g \rangle = G$.

*Definition*: Let $W$ be a representation of $G$, $K$ a subgroup of $G$, and $X$ a subspace of $W$.
 Let the *fixed-point subspace* $W^{K}:=\{w \in W \ \vert \  kw=w \ , \forall k \in K  \}$.
Let the *pointwise stabilizer subgroup* $G_{(X)}:=\{ g \in G \  \vert \ gx=x \ , \forall x \in X \}$.

*Definition*:  $[H,G]$ is called linearly primitive if $\exists V$ irred. complex repr. of $G$ with $G_{(V^H)} = H$. 
 *Remark:* $[1,G]$ is linearly primitive iff $G$ is [linearly primitive](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linearly_primitive_group).

**Question**: Let $[H, G]$ be a distributive interval of finite groups. Is $[H,G]$ linearly primitive?

*Remark:* The case $H = 1$ is true because $[1,G]=\mathcal{L}(G)$ is distributive iff $G$ is cyclic, but an abelian group is linearly primitive iff it is cyclic. It follows that it's also true if $H \triangleleft G$.

It's true by GAP for $|G:H|<32$ or $\vert G \vert \le 1000$ or $G$ perfect with $\vert G \vert < 10080$ (except $7680$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**

This was proved in the [planar algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_algebra) framework, see [arXiv:1704.00745](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.00745v3.pdf), Corollary 6.10.

For a self-contained group-theoretic proof, see [arXiv:1708.02565](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02565).