# When a complex representation which is free on the complement of the origin does exist?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

I became interested in the following question and realized that it was asked by Niko Bellic in the comment to [previous](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57129/which-finite-groups-have-faithful-complex-irreducible-representations) question of mine. For which finite groups a complex representation which is free on the complement of the origin does exist? Of course it may be a priori irreducible. In other words, how to describe  finite matrix groups for which $A-I$ is invertible for all $A\ne I$ in the group? For Abelian groups only cyclic groups satisfy this property.

Comment: It looks to me like finite Heisenberg groups also work.  For an integer $\ell > 1$, consider the group $G$ with cyclic center $Z(G) = \langle z | z^\ell \rangle$ given by $G=\langle x,y,z | z^\ell, x^\ell = z = y^\ell, yx = z xy \rangle$.  Consider the $\ell$-dimensional representation that sends $x$ to a "cyclic" shift matrix $\mathbf{e}_i = \zeta \mathbf{e}_{i+1}$ for $\zeta$ a primitive $\ell^2$ root of unity, and that sends $y$ to the diagonal matrix $\mathbf{e}_i \mapsto \zeta^{1+i\ell} \mathbf{e}_i$.

Comment: These are precisely the Frobenius complements, well-studied in the literature, and they appear in some previous questions on here ( some of whose answers I have been involved with). They were already studied by Burnside though he made a famous error in one of his statements about them. It is true that the Sylow $q$-subgroups of a Frobenius complements are cyclic for odd $q$, and cyclic or generalized quaternion for $q = 2$. The only perfect Frobenius complement is ${\rm SL}(2,5)$ in either of its faithful $2$-dimensioal complex representation. A Frobenius complement of odd order is metacyclic,

Comment: Since finite Heisenberg groups are not metacyclic, that means my example does not work: even though $x$ and $y$ act freely for that representation, already $xy^{-1}$ has a nonzero fixed vector.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson. Our comments were posted at just about the same moment.  I also realized that my examples don't work.

Comment: @Jason Starr: OK, I deleted my second comment.